# Upstart job fails to respawn and hangs when tried to stop/restart it

Tags: boot, scripts, upstart, services, init

I'm using Upstart 1.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 to manage a process created by some user but needs to be managed as system job as starting on boot, respawning if it fails and we been able to start/stop it at any desired time so, I create it's .conf file in /etc/init and is as follows :

```
description "Start face services recognition and monitors it"
version "1.0"
start on runlevel[5]
stop on runlevel[06]
respawn
expect fork
normal exit 0 TERM STOP
script
exec sh -c /home/verstand/facefeatures
end script
post-stop script
if [ ! $EXIT_STATUS && ! $EXIT_SIGNAL ]
then
exec sudo -u $USER "/sbin/shutdown -r now"  
fi
end script
```

The signals here are intented to reboot the system in an emergency case where Upstart fails to respawn the process.

Now, the problem is when we start the process it runs fine, with `sudo initctl start facefeatures` but when we try to stop it, it hangs and we need to use Ctl+C to return tty control.
Even more, if we try to start it again or restart it, Upstart reports it's already running: `start/running facefeatures` but, if we use `initctl list` Upstart reports as if the process was killed: `stop/killed facefeatures`

Also, if we reboot the first time it runs the process normally but if we reboot a second time it does it no more...

What is the problem of my conf file? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: First, you should also post your script. Second, sudo -u $USER is going to return root, so you can just call shtudown without the sudo.

Comment: Which script I should also post? facefeatures is not a script, it's a complete c program.

Comment: from where ? did you write it ? is it working properly ?

Comment: Yes, it works properly alone and no, I didn't wrote it, my boss did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *facefeatures* is not a script, then I believe its a problem of upstart not knowing what process to watch. Do start it with *exec* and not with *script* stanza:

```
description "Start face services recognition and monitors it"
version "1.0"
start on runlevel[5]
stop on runlevel[06]
normal exit 0 TERM STOP
expect fork
respawn
exec /home/verstand/facefeatures
post-stop script
    if [ ! $EXIT_STATUS && ! $EXIT_SIGNAL ]
    then
        exec sudo -u $USER "/sbin/shutdown -r now"  
    fi
end script
```

When stopping the service your programm will receive a TERM, if it does no react on that signal it will get killed after five seconds.

Comment: You may want to add some information about 'expect fork' which you removed. If facefeatures forks and detaches, it may still be needed.

Comment: Yeah, tombert's point is a doubt arising...why removing the `respawn` and `expect fork` stanzas? I was reading a post in a blog I fail to remember to use `expect daemon` instead of `expect fork`

Comment: I removed `expect fork` because Kronos said that _facefeatures_ is a self written program. So I assumed the simplest case that this program does not daemonize. But I will change my comment, you might be right that I simplified too much.

Comment: No no, it's not a reclaim, I'm just trying to understand Upstart. _facefeatures_ does not daemonize itself but I need it to, so it can be run in the background. So `expect fork` waits the process it monitors to fork itself? So what does `expect daemon` does?

Comment: `expect fork` monitors the process if it `forks` (see man page) a child process. The PID of the child process then is the main process for upstart to watch. If this PID dies then upstart `respawns` your program. Generally there is no need that `facefeatures` daemonizes itself when running from _upstart_ because it will automatically run in background. For more details on _upstart_ you might want to have a look here http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect.